# cancelled pdf transfer from yosemite mac to iOS device via airdrop

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, macos, airdrop

I can send pictures from my mac to my iOS devices via airdrop. But when I try to send a pdf, it is not working. After a while I get a message on the iOS device saying that the transfer has been canceled. On the mac, I get a message saying that the iOS device has refused transfer. Is it normal? Is there a way to send my documents via airdrop (i know I can use dropbox but sometimes I do not have access to internet)?

Answer (score 1):

One way of transferring PDFs directly from a Mac to an iOS device is to drop them into iTunes. Once in iTunes you can transfer the PDFs to the iOS device and they will appear in iBooks on your device.

Comment: Thanks. But do you need a wifi network or a usb cable to sync the iOS device?

Comment: A USB cable will definitely work, syncing over wi-fi should work in theory, depending on device and configuration... https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203075

Comment: Yes you are right! I still wait to see if anyone comes up with a solution using airdrop as this should in principle be faster than having to sync the whole iphone / iPad